# AWK (unexpected newline or end of string) in Pig

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, apache-pig

I just compared the two directories and print the result in a text Document:

```
sh diff -r /root/bdataTest /root/bdataTest1 | grep /root/bdataTest | awk '{print $4}' > /root/test.txt
```

It shows Error like:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {print
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

What is the issue? How I can fix?

Comment: what is output of "sh diff -r /root/bdataTest /root/bdataTest1 | grep /root/bdataTest "

Comment: Is that the **exact** command that causes that output? Run **exactly** that way?